# Can an MVC Controller Action subscribe directly to SignalR Hub Events without jQuery involved? As a pure .NET SignalR Client, no JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to determine the dependency on jQuery on the client side. Basically, I would like a Controller to subscribe to the Hub and update the Controller Action (Redirect, ViewBag, etc) when a Hub method/event is fired. So far, I only find examples of jQuery hub connections that perform some updates to the view, like appending <li> to a <ul> for message output.

I keep hearing that you can do a pure .NET client implementation of SignalR from presentations found on Channel9, but can't seem to find how it is implemented. Code references/articles would be nice.

Comment: Try the documentation https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

Comment: The wiki doesn't cover the scenario as far as I can tell. Unless someone can definitively state that it's possible, I will have to assume that you need jQuery to keep the Hub alive and a Controller Action cannot "subscribe" to the Hub events.

Comment: Check https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client and https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs to be specific.